# Spark FlatMapGroupsWithStateFunction throws cannot resolve 'named_struct()' due to data type mismatch 'SerializeFromObject

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Am using FlatMapGroupsWithStateFunction in my spark streaming application.

```
 FlatMapGroupsWithStateFunction<String, Row, SessionInfo, SessionUpdate> idstateUpdateFunction =
  new FlatMapGroupsWithStateFunction<String, Row, SessionInfo, SessionUpdate>() {.....}
```

Session update class is as below;

```
  public static class SessionUpdate implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3858977319192658483L;

private String instanceId;

private ArrayList<GenericRowWithSchema> milestones = new ArrayList<GenericRowWithSchema>();

private Timestamp processingTimeoutTimestamp;

public SessionUpdate() { 
  super();
}

public SessionUpdate(String instanceId, ArrayList<GenericRowWithSchema> milestones, Timestamp processingTimeoutTimestamp) {
  super();
  this.instanceId = instanceId;
  this.milestones = milestones;
  this.processingTimeoutTimestamp = processingTimeoutTimestamp;
}

public String getInstanceId() {
  return instanceId;
}

public void setInstanceId(String instanceId) {
  this.instanceId = instanceId;
}

public ArrayList<GenericRowWithSchema> getMilestones() {
  return milestones;
}

public void setMilestones(ArrayList<GenericRowWithSchema> milestones) {
  this.milestones = milestones;
}

public Timestamp getProcessingTimeoutTimestamp() {
  return processingTimeoutTimestamp;
}

public void setProcessingTimeoutTimestamp(Timestamp processingTimeoutTimestamp) {
  this.processingTimeoutTimestamp = processingTimeoutTimestamp;
}
```

}

After adding below into the class I get the exception which is mentioned as below;

```
private ArrayList<GenericRowWithSchema> milestones = new ArrayList<GenericRowWithSchema>();
```

Exception:

```
ERROR  cannot resolve 'named_struct()' due to data type mismatch: input to function named_struct requires at least one argument;;
```

'SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, oracle.insight.spark.event_processor.EventProcessor$SessionUpdate, true]).getInstanceId, true, false) AS instanceId#62, mapobjects(MapObjects_loopValue2, MapObjects_loopIsNull2, ObjectType(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema), if (isnull(lambdavariable(MapObjects_loopValue2, MapObjects_loopIsNull2, ObjectType(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema), true))) null else named_struct(), assertnotnull(input[0, oracle.insight.spark.event_processor.EventProcessor$SessionUpdate, true]).getMilestones, None) AS milestones#63, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$, TimestampType, fromJavaTimestamp, assertnotnull(input[0, oracle.insight.spark.event_processor.EventProcessor$SessionUpdate, true]).getProcessingTimeoutTimestamp, true, false) AS processingTimeoutTimestamp#64]
+- FlatMapGroupsWithState , cast(value#54 as string).toString, createexternalrow(EventTime#23.toString, InstanceID#24.toString, Model#25.toString, Milestone#26.toString, Region#27.toString, SalesOrganization#28.toString, ProductName#29.toString, ReasonForQuoteReject#30.toString, ReasonforRejectionBy#31.toString, OpportunityAmount#32.toJavaBigDecimal, Discount#33.toJavaBigDecimal, TotalQuoteAmount#34.toJavaBigDecimal, NetQuoteAmount#35.toJavaBigDecimal, ApprovedDiscount#36.toJavaBigDecimal, TotalOrderAmount#37.toJavaBigDecimal, StructField(EventTime,StringType,true), StructField(InstanceID,StringType,true), StructField(Model,StringType,true), StructField(Milestone,StringType,true), StructField(Region,StringType,true), StructField(SalesOrganization,StringType,true), StructField(ProductName,StringType,true), StructField(ReasonForQuoteReject,StringType,true), StructField(ReasonforRejectionBy,StringType,true), ... 6 more fields), [value#54], [EventTime#23, InstanceID#24, Model#25, Milestone#26, Region#27, SalesOrganization#28, ProductName#29, ReasonForQuoteReject#30, ReasonforRejectionBy#31, OpportunityAmount#32, Discount#33, TotalQuoteAmount#34, NetQuoteAmount#35, ApprovedDiscount#36, TotalOrderAmount#37], obj#61: oracle.insight.spark.event_processor.EventProcessor$SessionUpdate, class[instanceId[0]: string, milestones[0]: array>, processingTimeoutTimestamp[0]: timestamp], Append, false, ProcessingTimeTimeout

Any clue why am I getting this exception?

thanks.